# Upgrading gojs to latest version

Tags: gojs

I have an existing gojs code base which is on version 1.8 , i wanted to upgrade to version 2.0 or           higher because it has some features that i require also what would be other dependencies.

**how to upgrade to latest version.**

Answer (score 0):

We were also used version 1.8

to upgrade version, all we do is just replace version 2.0 file in a web project